# How to strip phone number without ( ) or - in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I am coming to a problem where I need to strip phoneNumber on my table view cell without `()` or `-` so, I want to look this way `5555555555`, so when the user clicks on the phone number it should call that particular number.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      if indexPath.row == 2 {

        print("its working...")

        guard let phoneNumber = self.place.phoneNumber,
          phoneNumber.count > 0,

          let url = URL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)")

          else { return }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
          UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
      } else { return }
    }
```

Comment: None of the code you posted is related to stripping non-numeric characters from a string.

Comment: I need some help to strip that is why.. I am newbie in swift that is why you don't see related stripping non-numeric characters from a string.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I know exactly what you want to do. I understand your question. I'm simply pointing out that your question is asking how to remove non-numeric characters from a string. None of the code in your question is related to doing that.

Comment: Yes. Is there way you can show me a snippet of how it is going to work?

Comment: BTW - you do not need to remove those characters. You just need to properly encode the value of `phoneNumber` when building your URL.

Comment: mhmm... How is that going to work? Can you show me how I need to properly encode the value of `phoneNumber`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your goal is to create a valid `tel:` URL. You do not need to strip the formatting of the phone number. You just need to properly escape the special characters.

Replace:

```
let url = URL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)")
```

with:

```
let url = URL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!)")
```

Comment: is it all in string? because, i get a error with : `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'URL' with no arguments`

Comment: The code in my answer compiles with no errors for me but I'm using Xcode 9.4 (Swift 4.1).

Comment: It compiles now.. just missing a quotation mark at the end. thanks so much for the help.

Comment: More importantly, does the phone call actually work when run on a real device?

Answer (score 1):

You can strip number from a string with

```
let number = phoneNumber.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
```

Comment: So, this will be implemented  inside `didSelectRow`, right?

Comment: it still gives me an error with: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'`

Comment: there is no compile error you must have something irrelevant